# MySQL foreign key from existing data

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation: I need to create a column in an existing MySQL table which will act as a foreign key to another table. This table currently contains multiple records per person, I need a new column which will be unique for every person.

Example: `NC = new column`

```
NC   NAME    SURNAME   UNIT
1    john    doe       12
1    john    doe       15
2    peter   smith     17
3    bruce   twain     13
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use   alter table add column query to the existing table. it would not affect your data.

Comment: hi thank you for the response, yes im going to have to use alter table but how do i make a unique identifier based on name and surname?

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on your info:

1. make new Persons-table
2. add nc to "your table", referencing to Persons-table id
3. "another table" may reference to the Persons table

AFIU you want make many-to-many relation between "your table" and "another table", but from my experience is better to have reference table for foreign key (one-to-many from "your table" and "another table").